# ipsec binary on Centos 8

Tags: centos, vpn, strongswan

I've set up an ubuntu VM which connects to a Microsoft IKEv2 VPN, with the strongswan package (which depends on strongswan-charon and strongswan-starter). I control the vpn with the ipsec command, which comes from the strongswan-starter package.

When I install the strongswan package on a centos8 VM, it doesn't provide the ipsec command. Where do I find this command on Centos 8?

Answer (score 1):

According to [these instructions](https://kifarunix.com/configure-strongswan-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-18-04-centos-8/) you need to install the `strongswan` and `strongswan-charon-nm` packages (as root, use `sudo bash` before if appropriate):

```
# dnf install epel-release
# dnf update
# dnf install strongswan strongswan-charon-nm
```

The `ipsec` command is contained in the alternative (non-strongswan) package [libreswan](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/8-stream/appstream/x86_64/Packages/libreswan-3.32-6.el8.x86_64.html) but is is not needed (according to the instructions linked above) and likely incompatible.

However, with the CentOS 8 packages you can use the `strongswan` command like you would the `ipsec` command in Ubuntu:

```
root@ubuntu # ipsec up myvpn
root@centos # strongswan up myvpn
```

Comment: The ipsec command from the libreswan package is quite different to the ipsec/strongswan commands from ubuntu/rhel strongswan packages.

Comment: @frankster OK, thanks for testing, I have adjusted my answer. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that on RHEL8, the "strongswan" binary is the same as the "ipsec" binary from Ubuntu 20.04.

For example to start a VPN,on RHEL8 you would type "strongswan up myvpn", while on Ubuntu 20.04 you would type "ipsec up myvpn".